# Serial to USB-Host CDC

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, usb-host

I have a device that includes an USB-B port and, when connected to a computer, it appears as a virtual serial port and I can send AT commands to it.

I'm trying to create a board that will include an ESP32 that will connect to an App in my Phone using Bluetooth and the UART serial output of the ESP should "appear" into an USB-A connector that will then be connected to former device. This way I can setup such device without a computer.

There are a few processors that include USB host peripherals (including a few FTDI ones). But they all need to be programmed (for that I have to include one more connector to the board, maintain one more source code, they are all more expensive then the ESP32 itself, among other issues). I was looking for a simple converter like the FTDI that appear in most arduino boards, but in the other direction.

Here is the best approach by now (but costs the double of the ESP32 itself):

https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/DS_Vinculum-II.pdf

ESP also have ESP32-S3 that includes USB OTG but does not include Bluetooth, so no luck here.

Does anyone know a better approach to facilitate the USB host communication I need?

Comment: Maybe your device has some sort of USB-to-UART bridge? Like CP2102/FT232RL/CH340G/PL2303HX/etc? Does it requires some special driver under Windows?

Comment: Also take a look at FT312D. Seems like the only part for your needs... except for pre-programmed CH559 MCU from Tindie. Still both are pretty expensive.

Comment: Similar thread without solution: https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/suggest-good-usb-host-to-uart-converter-to-work-with-esp-wroom-32.160415/

Comment: Is this for quantity or one-off? If the latter, skip making a board and use a Pi Zero W?

Comment: @NStorm The devices you listed are on the wrong end of the cable. The question is about implementing a specialized USB host.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica if you read my answer and comment completely, you'll find out that I've mentioned these as exact the opposite part which won't suit as they work as USB Device, not the USB Host. My comment was actually about how it was implemented on the existing "side of the cable". Except for FT312D, which implements USB Host part.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a non trivial task. Basically you need an IC which will act as a bridge with a USB (OTG) Host on one side, and UART on the other. While there a lot of USB-UART bridges (CP2102, FT232, CH340G, PL2303HX, etc) they act as the USB Device and won't fit your needs.

It's really a little off-topic here to suggest exact parts, but seems like the only one that might suit your needs in a simple way is [FT312D](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/DS_FT312D.pdf). Which runs as USB OTG Host on the USB side indeed.

As you've already noted in your question, you can take some MCU with USB OTG Host hardware and turn it into your UART bridge with custom firmware. There are even might be some opensource examples to build one quickly. But yes, that will make things more complicated as you've already noted.

Honestly the best approach is usually to pick appropriate part for the task. In your example I mean get an MCU with Bluetooth stack and USB OTG Host. Some are available from different vendors (STM32WBx5, RA4W1, CH579, etc). At least this is what is usually done in production. But that will involve programming on a different platform. So it's up to you to decide if want to get into this.

Comment: On my search I've found the FT312D but all its documentation says it uses the android platform. Maybe was a mistake to discard it without knowing what exactly "android" means in this context. Will give it a new try. Another thing: CH579 is awesome! stock is zero but its price is amasing (taking in account all it does)!!

Comment: @GustavoVargas I think they mention Android because it's not complete USB Host solution, but rather limited USB OTG with only some of the device classes supported. It just suits Android as it does supports only some of the classes too (out of box) but it should fit your needs because you need CDC class only for UART. But that is strictly a guess because I didn't had personal experience with it.

Answer (score 2):

As other people said, this is not a trivial task. But it might be not *too* complex either. It all depends on the USB class that your device uses to communicate. BTW this was the first question @NStorm asked you in the comments, and you ignored it. Too bad, because it makes a difference between "relatively simple" and "very hard".

First thing to understand, is that in order for host to convert USB device into UART port it needs device driver that knows exact protocol used by device. Just because your device appears as virtual serial port does not mean it uses some universally recognized protocol. For example many USB-to-UART chips, including very common FT232R, do need their own drivers installed on Windows.

This means that even if you find MCU that has both BLE and USB Host hardware, you still have to write a driver to talk to your device. Normally, this would be true for a Vinculum chip that you discovered yourself too.

However there is a big chance that your device uses CDC class to create virtual COM port with help of built-in [Usbser.sys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-driver-installation-based-on-compatible-ids) driver. In this case you may be able to find enough information on the web to make similar driver in your MCU. See relevant articles [here](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/mw/USB/html/dev_cdc_tutorial.html) and [here](http://janaxelson.com/usb_virtual_com_port.htm), for example.

But even better news is that FTDI supplies a lot of [precompiled firmware](https://ftdichip.com/firmware/precompiled/) for their Vinculum chip that you can use right away, no coding necessary. And one of them is [UART to CDC Bridge](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_183_Vinculum-II_UART_to_CDCModem_Host_Bridge.pdf). To put it simply, it basically has CDC modem driver built-in, that "creates" a virtual serial port inside for the connected USB device, and then connects this virtual port to physical UART pins of the chip.

If you get lucky and your device is recognized by the bridge firmware then this would be probably simplest "no coding necessary" solution for you.

P.S. I must agree with @hobbs comment though. If this is one-off project then using Pi Zero W could be cheapest and most efficient way to go. Most likely you will find the driver for your device and a lot of open source code to communicate with your phone.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know a better approach to facilitate the USB host
> communication I need?

UARTS are much simpler than USB (but have reduced bandwidth just sending commands does not require a large amount of bandwidth). Most devices support UARTS (RS232) and sending AT commands over them. The amount of programming would be setting the baud rate on both devices and correctly routing TX and RX. You may need to do minimal programming on the receiving side which usually involves parsing the text, nearly every programming language that I know of can handle a serial stream.

Edit:

While I have never done it you can do serial over BLE which would also simplify programming.

Comment: Not sure If I misunderstood you, or if you misunderstood my question.... :)

Comment: The answer is: you have to program if you do USB, it is unavoidable and it isn't trivial most of the time. If you want to save time and don't want to program, don't use USB. (or use serial over BLE or serial over USB)